# What is the easiest way to apply database functionality into my daily life?

Tags: database

let me try to explain it by listing some of the things I want to do:

1. Submit random thoughts, notes, facts, and to-do tasks of any sort and at any time.
2. Tag each of these submissions freely.
3. Manage these tags centrally.
4. Associate meta-data with submissions and tags.
5. Search, filter, and sort submissions.  I want lots of power here.
6. Display views of submissions (including within searches) in a hierarchy.
7. Create said hierarchies easily out by ordering relevant tags.
8. **Edit:** Publish select submissions (e.g. when given certain tags) to a blog or local text file or something similar.

I'm thinking towards some kind of desktop program that allows me to quickly do all of these things.  A web service could also work, too, but it will need offline capabilities.  I don't want to have to pay for this, if that's possible.

Also, as I know regex and SQL, I wouldn't mind solutions involving the use of either.

Answer (score 2):

[Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) ticks most (all?) of your boxes.

Comment: Indeed, also check out Getting Things Done by David Allen, I'm planning on reading it after my exams as I heard a lot of good things about it.

Comment: I'll check this out again, but keep in mind my heavy emphasis on searching, filtering, and sorting (and hierarchy viewing, if possible).  Not sure this will meet my needs...

Comment: ...no it doesn't.  No way to make hierarchies.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

[DEVONthink](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonthink/) ($49.95) and [Yojimbo](http://www.barebones.com/products/yojimbo/) ($39) are two commercial Mac OS X apps that do most or all of that.  Yojimbo is easier to use but may not handle the posting to blog requirement.